# Integral involving a Dirac delta

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, dirac-delta, pseudoinverse

The following result is provided in the [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) (Equation 547): If $\mathbf{A}$ is an $m \times k$ matrix with linearly independent columns and $m > k$, then
\begin{align}
\int f(\mathbf{x}) \, \delta( \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}) d \mathbf{x} = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{\det ( \mathbf{A}^{T} \mathbf{A} )^{\frac{1}{2}}} f( \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{y} ) & \text{if } (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^{+}) \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{0}, \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Here $f: \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a well-behaved function, $\delta(\mathbf{y})$ is a multivariate Dirac delta, and $\mathbf{A}^{+} = (\mathbf{A}^{T} \mathbf{A})^{-1} \mathbf{A}^T$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $\mathbf{A}$.
I found the [cited proof](https://web.archive.org/web/20040915164126/http://www.imm.dtu.dk/%7Emad/papers/madrix.pdf) of this result (Equation 6), but I don't understand it.
In particular, I do not understand how the Dirac delta is factorised and moved outside the integral during the proof.
How do I prove this result?

Comment: What does $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{y}$ mean?

Comment: The matrix $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^{+}$ projects $\mathbf{y}$ into $\mathbf{A}$'s column space. I believe the notation means the result is only non-zero if $\mathbf{y}$ is already within $\mathbf{A}$'s column space. It could be read as $(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^{+} ) \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{0}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We proceed as following
$$
\int f(\mathbf{x}) \, \delta( \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}) d \mathbf{x}
{=
\int f(\mathbf{x}) \, \delta( \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}) d \mathbf{x}.
}
$$
If $y$ doss not belong to the column space of $A$, then $\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}$ will never become zero. Otherwise, there is some $\mathbf{u}$ such that $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}$. By using Moore-Penrose inverse, we obtain
$$
\mathbf{A}^+\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{A}^+\mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}=\mathbf{I}_k \mathbf{u}= \mathbf{u}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int f(\mathbf{x}) \, \delta( \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}) d \mathbf{x}.
{
=
\int f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{u}) \, \delta( \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{A} (\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{u})) d \mathbf{x}
\\=
\int f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{u}) \, \delta( \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u}) d \mathbf{x}
\\=
\int f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{u}) \, \delta(  \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}) d \mathbf{x}.
}
$$
By definition of Dirac's delta function, we can write $\delta(\mathbf{x})=\delta(|\mathbf{x}|)$, where $|\mathbf{x}|$ is the norm of $\mathbf{x}$. Therefore,
$$
\int f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{u}) \, \delta(  \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}) d \mathbf{x}
{
=
\int f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{u}) \, \delta(  |\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}|) d \mathbf{x}
\\=
\int f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{u}) \, \delta\left(  \sqrt{\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}}\right) d \mathbf{x}.
}
$$
Now, it is time for a coordinate transformation. By defining the new coordinate system $\mathbf{\tilde x}=(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{x}$, the Jacobian matrix will be
$$
\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{\tilde x})=\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{d\mathbf{\tilde x}}=(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})^{-\frac{1}{2}}.
$$
Hence,
$$
\int f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{u}) \, \delta\left(  \sqrt{\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}}\right) d \mathbf{x}
{
=
\int d \mathbf{\tilde x} \det(J( \mathbf{\tilde x}))f((\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{\tilde x}+\mathbf{u}) \\\times \delta\left(  \sqrt{\mathbf{\tilde x}^T(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A} (\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{\tilde x}}\right)   
\\=
\int f((\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{\tilde x}+\mathbf{u}) \, \delta\left(  \sqrt{\mathbf{\tilde x}^T\mathbf{\tilde x}}\right)  \det(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})^{-\frac{1}{2}} d \mathbf{\tilde x}
\\=
\int f((\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{\tilde x}+\mathbf{u}) \, \delta\left( \mathbf{\tilde x}\right)  \det(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})^{-\frac{1}{2}} d \mathbf{\tilde x}
\\=
f(\mathbf{u})\det(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})^{-\frac{1}{2}}
\\=
f(\mathbf{A}^+\mathbf{y})\det(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})^{-\frac{1}{2}}
\blacksquare
}
$$

Comment: The first equation appears to be a tautology. In the last two lines you replaced $\bf u$ with ${\bf A}^+{\bf u}$, and I think you meant ${\bf A}^+{\bf y}$, but then I have another question... if the result is $f({\bf u})/\sqrt{\det A^TA}$ for any solution $\bf u$ to ${\bf y}={\bf Au}$, but $f({\bf u})$ depends on which solution $\bf u$ we pick, then how is this consistent?

Comment: The first one was a typo and got fixed. For your second question, I should add in fair that there is **only one** such $\mathbf{u}$. This is because the columns of $\mathbf{A}$ are linearly independent and having two different values for $\mathbf{u}$ violates this assumption. More rigorously, if $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u}_1=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u}_2$, then $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{u}_1-\mathbf{u}_2)=\mathbf{0}$ and this implies $\mathbf{u}_1=\mathbf{u}_2$.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that assumption.

Comment: To further expose my ignorance: How do you define a multivariate Dirac delta? It's often given as a product of univariate Dirac deltas over the $m$ elements of the vector $\mathbf{x}$: $\delta(\mathbf{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^{m} \delta (x_{i})$. Does this mean the multivariate Dirac delta is undefined if $\mathbf{x}$ has a single element equal to zero? If, as you say, $\delta(\mathbf{x}) = \delta( |\mathbf{x}|)$, then the Dirac delta is only undefined when $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$? I feel like I'm making an obvious mistake here.

Comment: A multivariate $n$-dimensional delta function should preserve the essential property that it is zero throughout $\Bbb R^n$, except at one point. If a multivariate delta function is defined as the product of univariate deltas, then it will not be well-defined. For example, it would be ambiguous as to what value $\delta(x_1)\delta(x_2)$ possesses when $x_1=0$ and $x_2\ne 0$.

Comment: Is the multivariate Dirac delta that arises in Fourier analysis well defined? I believe it's given by  $\delta(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{ (2 \pi)^{m} } \int_{\mathbb{R}^{m}} \exp \big( i \mathbf{s}^{T} \mathbf{x} \big) d \mathbf{s}$. This is the definition I've been using for a multivariate Dirac delta, and I believed it reduced to a product of univariate Dirac deltas. Is my definition incorrect? Or is there something subtle I got wrong that does not allow it to be simplified?

Comment: Your definition is not wrong, but note that if for some $k$ we have $x_k\ne0$, the integral vanishes. In particular,$$\delta(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^m}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(\imath s_kx_k)dx_k\prod_{j=1,j\ne k}^m\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(\imath s_jx_j)dx_j=0.$$We have defined $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(ix)dx=0$.